# I want to remove the row if that row's <td> contains only B in my below code?

Tags: jquery

Please check the below code. Here i'm deleting the row, if that row td contains the value "B". But bellow code is removing all rows.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mytable tr td:contains('B')").parent().remove();
});
```

HTML

```
<table border="0" align="center" width="45%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2"  id="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="15%">A</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">B</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="15%">AA</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">BB</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">CC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="15%">AAA</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">BBB</td>
        <td align="center" width="15%">CCC</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: All the rows have a 'B' in them.  Do you only want to remove the cells?

Answer (score 9):

To remove the `tr` where a `td` within it contains *ONLY* `B`

```
var searchString = 'B';
$("#mytable tr td:contains('" + searchString + "')").filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == searchString;
}).parent().remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/Ps7G4/155)

To remove only the `td` which contains a `B`:

The `parent()` is putting the selector on the `tr`, which is then being removed - along with all `td` elements. You don't need to use `parent()` here.

```
$("#mytable tr td:contains('B')").remove();
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nqMLL/)

Comment: As I understand it, he wants to remove the rows.

Comment: That's how it reads, but his code already does that - so I assumed that wasn't what he was trying to do.

Comment: As I understand it he wants to remove the row with "B", but not "BB" or "BBB".

Comment: @RoToRa You could be right - I've updated my answer for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Sandeep Try this.

```
     $(document).ready(function()
     {
        $("#mytable td").text(function(index, currentText) 
        {
            if(currentText.trim()=='B')
                $(this).parent().remove();
        }); 
    });
```

Comment: Why? This is overly complicated. `:contains` works just fine.

Comment: The question is to remove table row. So I'm checking each <td>

Comment: @elclanrs As I understand it he wants to remove the row with "B", but not "BB" or "BBB", and `:contains` matches sub strings, so it doesn't work here.

Comment: @Hearaman You'll need to add an `each` or `filter` to loop over the cells.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Not sure if this is the best possible regex but it works. It'll remove the `<tr>` which contains a `<td>` with only one uppercase `B`. http://jsfiddle.net/mV4z3/

```
$('td').filter(function(){ 
    return /^B$/.test($(this).text()); 
}).parent().remove();
```